# Como formatar uma data no formato 'dd/MM/yyyy'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

Como obter uma string formatada de um objeto do tipo `Date` no formato `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Utilize os filtros do AngularJS

Para formatar as datas no Angular, existe o [Angular Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) que é muito útil e fácil de usar, seja na `view` ou nos `controllers`. O `filter` ainda pode ser usado para formatar qualquer tipo de objeto. Para data existem várias combinações possíveis.

### Como usar filters?

#### Em um template HTML

`{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}`

#### No código javascript (Diretivas, controllers, etc)

`$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)`

### Como formatar datas?

Você pode converter seu objeto do tipo Date em qualquer `string` baseado na configurações, veja alguns exemplos:

- `yyyy` ano com 4 dígitos
- `MM` mês com 2 dígitos (01-12)
- `M` mês com 1 ou 2 dígitos (1-12)
- `dd` dia com dois dígitos (01-31)
- `d`dia com 1 ou 2 dígitos (1-31)
- ou veja a lista completa na [documentação do Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Há ainda a possibilidade de adicionar o [Angular Locale](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale) em seu projeto para utilizar os formatos no idioma que desejar, no nosso caso [PT-BR](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngLocale/angular-locale_pt-br.js) ou [PT-PT](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngLocale/angular-locale_pt-pt.js).

### Exemplo de código - Template HTML

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', myController);

myController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function myController($scope) {
  $scope.data = new Date(2014, 11 - 1, 13, 17, 17, 47, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <p><b>Valor original:</b> {{ data }}</p>
  <p><b>dd/MM/yyyy:</b> {{ data | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</p>
  <p><b>Data completa:</b> {{ data | date: 'fullDate' }}</p>
</div>
```

### Exemplo de código - Controller

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', myController);

myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];

function myController($scope, $filter) {
  var data = new Date(2014, 11 - 1, 13, 17, 17, 47, 0);
  $scope.data = data;
  $scope.dataFormatada = $filter('date')(data, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <p><b>Original:</b> {{ data }}</p>
  <p><b>Formatada:</b> {{ dataFormatada }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Eita, tava fazendo um exemplo no controller e não vi que já tinha editado :p

Comment: @Techies coloquei logo depois.. hehe De qualquer forma vou usar seu link do locale na minha resposta.

Comment: Tranquilo, rs eu que não tinha visto.

Answer (score 6):

A resposta do @Pedro já responde sua dúvida, porém gostaria de mostrar um exemplo onde podemos trabalhar com filtros direto no `Controller`:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $filter){
 var data = "2016-02-18T10:23Z";
     $scope.dataFormatada = $filter('date')(data, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Data Formatada, {{dataFormatada}}!
</div>
```

OBS: Para trabalhar com datas no nosso formato recomendo dar uma olhada no [locale](https://github.com/renato/bower-angular-locale-pt-br)

Answer (score 5):

este filtro me ajuda a lidar com os timestamps

dateFilter.js

```
angular.module("zendapp").filter("brdateFilter", function(){
return function(input) {
    var o = input.replace(/-/g, "/"); // Troca hifen por barra
    return Date.parse(o + " -0000"); 
};
});
```

index.html

```
{{row.created_at.date | brdateFilter | date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}}
```