# Formatar data AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou com um problema para formatar a hora que aparece na View, ela esta vindo da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém gostaria que ela fosse exibida no formato "hh:mm:ss". 
O código html é o seguinte:

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!salvo" required ng-model="notaServico.dataEmissao" />
```

Como faço para formatar ela no angularJS ou até mesmo no próprio HTML?

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual versão do angular você está utilizando?

Comment: Você precisa utilizar os filtros do Angular, veja [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113894/como-formatar-uma-data-no-formato-dd-mm-yyyy/113895#113895) que explico como fazer. No seu caso você precisará usar o formato `HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: Veja na [documentação(em inglês)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) todos os formatos que você pode utilizar.

Comment: @miltoncamara não é duplicata. Ele quer formatar a hora dentro de um `input`. Fora que não é uma data completa.

Comment: @miltoncamara  eu havia olhado este post, porém no meu caso eu teria que formatar esta hora em um input, eu testei a forma deste post porém só funcionou com label, oque não é meu caso rs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resposta adaptada de: [como-formatar-uma-data-no-formato-dd-mm-yyyy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113894/como-formataar-uma-data-no-formato-dd-mm-yyyy)

## Utilize os filtros do AngularJS

Para formatar as datas no Angular, existe o [Angular Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) que é muito útil e fácil de usar, seja na `view` ou nos `controllers`. O `filter` ainda pode ser usado para formatar qualquer tipo de objeto. Para data existem várias combinações possíveis.

### Como usar filters?

#### No código javascript (Diretivas, controllers, etc)

`$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)`

### Como formatar horas?

Você pode converter seu objeto do tipo Date em qualquer `string` baseado na configurações, veja alguns exemplos:

- `HH` hora com dois dígitos (00-23) - 24 horas
- `H` hora com um dígito (0-23) - 24 horas
- `hh` hora com dois dígitos (01-12) - 12 horas
- `h` hora com um dígito (1-12) - 12 horas
- `mm` minutos com dois dígitos (00-59)
- `m` minutos com um dígito (0-59)
- `ss` segundos com dois dígitos (00-59)
- `s` segundos com um dígito (0-59)
- veja a lista completa na [documentação do Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

### Como aplicar isso no seu input?

Você deve injetar no seu controller o serviço `filter`do angular, e então formatar o valor com o formato que você precisa.

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', myController);

myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];

function myController($scope, $filter) {
  var dataHora = new Date();
  $scope.hora = dataHora;
  $scope.horaFormatada = $filter('date')(dataHora, 'HH:mm:ss');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <label>Hora sem formato</label><br />
  <input type="time" ng-model="hora" /><br />
  <label>Hora formatada</label><br />
  <input type="time" ng-model="horaFormatada" />
</div>
```

Comment: Legal sua resposta. Mas como ela responde a pergunta do AP? Como é possível aplicar isso num input?

Comment: Ah pois é.. esqueci dessa parte.. vou editar. :)

Comment: @LINQ acho que agora está respondendo a dúvida do AP.

Comment: Uh, ficou ótimo.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou :D

Answer (score 0):

Tenta esse código (*javascript*):

```
function time_format(d) {
    hours = format_two_digits(d.getHours());
    minutes = format_two_digits(d.getMinutes());
    seconds = format_two_digits(d.getSeconds());
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

function format_two_digits(n) {
    return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
}
```

Já utilizei uma vez, encontrei [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346405/jquery-how-to-get-hhmmss-from-date-object).

**Adicionado após comentário**

Podes chamar a formatação do campo no *onchange* do *input*:

```
$("#id_input").on("change", function(){
    $(this).val(time_format($this).val());
});
```

Comment: Legal sua resposta. Mas como ela responde a pergunta do AP? Como é possível aplicar isso num input?

Comment: Sua reposta conflita com a utilização do `AngularJS`. Em adição você está utilizando `JQuery`, o que não está especificado na pergunta do AP.